# Parallel execution in splitscreen?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, console, xargs, parallelism

I'm very well aware, that I can use `xargs` to run commands in parallel. However since the consoleout of the commands is important I was wondering if I could split the console window similar to how `screen` allows you to split the console window.

So is there a way I could convert a script like the following to run n parallel while each execution is shown inside it's own console "window"?

```bsh
for file in directory/*; do
    command1 $file
    command2 args $file ...
    etc
done
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `xterm -e command1 & xterm -e command2`?

Comment: @dessert no more like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QtRQmjBA3b8/maxresdefault.jpg But automated.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/954051/507051 offers two approaches, the second (see the answer's bottom) being to redirect a command's output to another terminal using e.g. `command > /dev/pts/1` – maybe this suits your need?

Comment: @dessert Not quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to just use one console window. So I can also use the split screen over SSH.

Comment: And you are not able to redirect a command's output to a split terminal? How so?

Comment: I have been told `screen` works fairly well over SSH.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how I could create a split terminal I can redirect the command outputs to

Comment: So that's what's the question? I think you should rephrase your question and explain why exactly `screen` doesn't work for you.

Comment: The point is I have no idea how to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel (> version 20180122):

```
parallel --tmux --fg echo ::: 1 2 3 4
```